# Dropdown menu hidden behind content on page?

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to make a navbar as an exercise but I got stuck. I have a navbar of height x and a inline-block nav-menu of variable height that contains a nav-button block of height x and nav-dropdown block of variable height. The overflow on the nav-menu is hidden (which is the nav-dropdown) until there is a hover over it.

The problem is when the nav-dropdown appears, it is behind the content on the page.

I attempted to add z-index to every single element including the top most parent to no avail.

Please see js-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wek84cx7/

The navbar configuration is below (presumably one would have multiple nav-menus):

```
<div class="navbar" style="z-index: 999;">

    <div class="nav-menu" style="z-index: 999;">
        <div class="nav-button" style="z-index: 999;">
            <div class="vertical-align-helper"></div>
            <span style="vertical-align: center;">Hello World</span>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-dropdown" style="z-index: 999;">
            <ul style="z-index: 999;">
                <li style="z-index: 999;">onee</li>
                <li style="z-index: 999;">twot</li>
                <li style="z-index: 999;">threeo</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the `.nav-bar` element. That will set the z-index stack order for it ... usually setting any position value other than `static` (the default) establishes a new stack order, otherwise, z-index gets ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting the z-index of the nav dropdown to something higher than the body.   In this case, you're setting a high z-index on everything, which isn't very productive.

I'd set a z-index of 20 or so on the nav and a z-index of 1 on the body like so:

```
.nav-dropdown {
    z-index: 20;
}
body {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Hope this helps.